# Do enums need an index?

Tags: c#, enums

I have a number of enums that contain long lists that do change from time to time

```
public MyEnumType MyEnum
{
    None = 0,
    Option1 = 1,
    Option2 = 2,
    etc..
}
```

When they change, I need to renumber the index as invariably new options are placed inbetween existing options.

The question is, if I remove the index, will the enum always honour the order from top to bottom?

```
public MyEnumType MyEnum
{
    None,
    Option1,
    Option2,
    etc..
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Clearly, it will. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: It will, but I don't see why it is important ? Since the whole point of an enum is "hiding" the integer values behind ^^

Comment: I've removed `asp.net` tag, because there's nothing related to it here.

Comment: @C4stor: That's not the only reason for enums. Another is to remove magic numbers and give them a meaning. This is especially true when interacting with external systems.

Comment: C4stor: not always. With Flagged enums you explicitely set their values to 1, 2, 4, 8 etc.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth That's not really the point of an enum. Better option: class with integer constants

Comment: @ose: What makes you say that?

Comment: Why do you need the number? If you are serialising to a file, not specifying the number will likely lead to pain if you change the order and try to load again. Is there some reason you need to use the index number?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth A magic number arises from the absence of proper use of a constant. Often these constants are related. So, we could (and many people who come from C do) use an enum to group the related constants. However, very often these "magic numbers" end up being used somewhere (eg. written to files, output to ports etc.) and possibly involve mathematical manipulation. This is somewhat inconsistent with the purpose of an enum which is to completely hide (at compile time) the underlying integers.

Comment: @ose: If that would be true, there wouldn't be implicit conversions in both directions. I guess we have to agree to disagree here.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I must disagree, an explicit cast is required to for conversion from enum to int http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx

Comment: @ose: Ha, you are right. Oops :-)

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I wouldn't have checked the reference were it not for your comment. We both learn something today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest answer would be "Yes"... they will always honor the order.

So you no need to put index number.

```
public MyEnumType MyEnum
{
    None,
    OptionA,
    OptionB,
    OptionC,
    ...
    ...
    OptionZ
}
```

this will always same as -

```
public MyEnumType MyEnum
{
    None = 0,
    OptionA = 1,
    OptionB = 2,
    OptionC = 3,
    ...
    ...
    OptionZ = 26
}
```

If you introduce new enum type in between like -

```
public MyEnumType MyEnum
{
    None,
    OptionA,
    OptionB,
    OptionC,
    ...
    ...
    OptionO
    OptionNew
    OptionP
    ...
    ...
    OptionZ
}
```

Then above will be equivalent to -

```
public MyEnumType MyEnum
{
    None = 0,
    OptionA = 1,
    OptionB = 2,
    OptionC = 3,
    ...
    ...
    OptionO = 15
    OptionNew = 16
    OptionP = 17
    ...
    ...
    OptionZ = 27
}
```

Comment: If you say _"Yes"... they will always honor the order_ you should prove that with the documentation(either MSDN or even the C# language specification). Otherwise it's just an assumption. Note that things that aren't documented are implementation details that might change in future releases of the .NET framework >> [**Docs**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [**language specification**](http://en.csharp-online.net/ECMA-334:_21.3_Enum_members).

Answer (score 6):

Yes they will.
You can also specify just the first element if you want to make sure that values start at some specific value:

```
public MyEnumType MyEnum
{
    None = 1,
    Option1, // -> 2
    Option2, // -> 3
}
```

For other details, check [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Note that in most scenarios, your code should not care about the exact numeric values.
Situations when you do care are e.g. if you declare an enum which is an alias for an external type (e.g interop) so you need to ensure that values are the same. Another scenario is when the enumeration represents binary flags, then you want something like:

```
[Flags] 
public MyEnumType MyEnum
{
    None = 1,
    Option1 = 2,
    Option2 = 4
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes they honour the order, starting from the default value for int, which is zero.

If you are regularly renumbering things then it is better to explicitly assign values to the enum members, and then re-number the items when the underlying list that it is based on changes.

If you use explicit numbering then you can also insert new items into the list between existing items at any time, although you do need to be careful that you don't assign two items to the same value (which is totally legal in C#, but may produce errors if you didn't intend it).

Answer (score 1):

From the [C# language specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms228593.aspx) 1.10 `Enums`:

> ... When an enum member declaration does not explicitly specify a value,
>   the member is given the value zero (if it is the first member in the
>   enum type) or the value of the textually preceding enum member plus
>   one.

So the same as your explicit declaration here:

```
public MyEnumType MyEnum
{
    None = 0,
    Option1 = 1,
    Option2 = 2,
    etc..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default they will count up from zero in the order they are declared.
If you define one explicitly, then the subsequent values continue counting up, using the explicit value as a seed.